# How can I go back/route-back on vue-router?

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

Ok, to explain this simply:

I have 3x pages.

- Page 1 (Home)
- Page 2 (Menu)
- Page 3 (About)

Page 1 has a-

```
<router-link to="/menu">
```

button that when clicked routes to "/menu".

For now, Page 2 (Menu) has a

```
<router-link to="/">
```

button and when this button is clicked it reverts to the previous location "/" Page 1 (Home).

But I don't want to create a component for router for each page to 'go back' to the previous page (as if I had 100 pages this could be a lot of work routing back). Is there a way to do this with vue-router? similar to `window.history.back()`

I'm curious to see if there is a way to do this as I can't find it in the docs.

Comment: [router.go(n) | Programmatic Navigation | vue-router](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/navigation.html#routergon)

Comment: @yuriy636's is probably the best answer. Currently we have and outer component with the back button which uses string manipulation on the current url to go back to the last page in the route. We will probably change to the router.go method when we get the chance now though

Comment: Ok thanks! It was staring me right in the face! I'm not really sure how to write this into my syntax though. Sorry! I'm new to this!

Answer (score 294):

You can use [Programmatic Navigation](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/navigation.html). In order to go back, you use this:

```
router.go(n)
```

Where `n` can be positive or negative (to go back). This is the same as `history.back()`.So you can have your element like this:

```
<a @click="$router.go(-1)">back</a>
```

Comment: Anyone had any issue with this on IE11? E.g if I open a page via router-link, click my button it goes back, however if I open the same page via router-link the `router.go(-1)` clears my URL but nothing happens.

Comment: I want to go back to previous page if there is no id on load, it works but on page refresh .go(-1) goes 2 pages back rather than 1 page.

Comment: Noob question, is it ok that we are using `a` tag here instead of router-link

Comment: @Hego555 I believe router-link is a component that renders an `a` tag by default

Comment: This seems to ignore any url params that were in the previous url you are going back to

Comment: Route-links are usefull to generate links to certain routes because it automatically generated the correct urls when you change history mode on or off.

Comment: I don't understand why does everybody use @click event on buttons/hyperlinks? It's not accessible, you can't click with your keyboard! What do instead is create a form with a submit handler which will do the logic, then create a submit button inside the form. How do you make an accessible link though? How do you make a programmatic link that shows the route in the browser's bottom left corner (as if the src of the link is set, not an event)?

Comment: but its clear params id , i have one page for create and view data . when i am on view data , then go to other page then go back , its on create data not view data . do u have solution ?

Answer (score 44):

Use `$router.back()` directly to go back/route-back programmatic on vue-router. Or if in the template of the component use `router.back()`.

Comment: it's `$router.back()`

Comment: @aspirinemaga it's not if you are using it in the template of the component, if that is the case you pass it as to="router.back()"

Answer (score 33):

This works like a clock for me:

```
methods: {
 hasHistory () { return window.history.length > 2 }
}
```

Then, in the template:

```
<button 
  type="button"    
  @click="hasHistory() 
    ? $router.go(-1) 
    : $router.push('/')" class="my-5 btn btn-outline-success">&laquo; 
  Back
</button>
```

Comment: If you come from another website external to your app, you think that you can go back to a previous page of your app, but you would actually leave it for an external website.

Answer (score 13):

Worked for me, short and practical. (Nuxt.js)

```
<a @click="$router.back()"></>
```

Answer (score 6):

If you're using `Vuex` you can use https://github.com/vuejs/vuex-router-sync

Just initialize it in your main file with:

```
import VuexRouterSync from 'vuex-router-sync';
VuexRouterSync.sync(store, router);
```

Each route change will update `route` state object in `Vuex`.
You can next create `getter` to use the `from` Object in route state or just use the `state` (better is to use getters, but it's other story
https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/getters.html),
so in short it would be (inside components methods/values):

```
this.$store.state.route.from.fullPath
```

You can also just place it in `<router-link>` component:

```
<router-link :to="{ path: $store.state.route.from.fullPath }"> 
  Back 
</router-link>
```

So when you use code above, link to previous path would be dynamically generated.

Comment: this causes an infinite loop problem

Comment: @TonyGW No it doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

This answer to this question becomes much trickier if you're coding a mobile app as you now need an integrated solution that accommodates back history from either your UI back button OR the "back" button provided by the mobile device!

Frameworks like [Ionic](https://ionicframework.com/) and [Quasar](https://quasar.dev) can intercept mobile device back button events. Quasar handles these events for you and adapts behaviour for desktop and mobile platform builds so a for example a Cordova/Capacitor mobile app build will ensure that a "back" action can intelligently either close a dialog or go back a page or even close the app!

- Quasar Back event handler and `v-go-back` directive

  - https://quasar.dev/vue-directives/go-back
- Ionic - Back button and Hardware back button

  - https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/back-button
  - https://ionicframework.com/docs/developing/hardware-back-button

Comment: Quasar v2 no longer provides this directive and link is now broken. It does still intercept back with a different approach. See https://quasar.dev/quasar-plugins/dialog#cordova-capacitor-back-button and https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/developing-capacitor-apps/configuring-capacitor#quasar-conf-js

Answer (score 0):

This might help someone

```
<router-link class="inner-back d-inline-block" to="">
    <i class="fas fa-arrow-left" @click="$router.go(-1)"></i>
</router-link>
```

Answer (score -5):

Another solution is using [vue-router-back-mixin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-router-back-mixin)

```
import BackMixin from `vue-router-back-mixin`

export default {
  ...
  mixins: [BackMixin],
  methods() {
    goBack() {
      this.backMixin_handleBack()
    }
  }
  ...
}
```