# vue2 go back without clear params on recently push

Tags: vue.js

i have 4 pages

1. list home [ Home.vue ]
2. create home [ CreateOrView.vue ]
3. view home [ CreateOrView.vue ]
4. summary [ Summary.vue ]

from page `list home` i have 2 button

- first button

```
:to="{
                name: 'view-home',
                params: {
                  id: props.row.detail_id,
                  api: 'view_home'
                }
              }"'
```

- second button

```
:to="{
                name: 'summary',
                params: {
                  id: props.row.detail_id,
                  api: 'view_home'
                }
              }"'
```

then on page `view home`

```
:to="{
                name: 'summary',
                params: {
                  id: props.row.detail_id,
                  api: 'view_home'
                }
              }"'
```

the last one page `summary`
i have **back button** with router back or go(n) like these https://stackoverflow.com/a/48123669/8122500

---

**unExpected :** list home --> view home --> summary --> go back --> create home

**expected :** list home --> view home --> summary --> go back --> view home

**expected :** list home --> summary --> go back --> list home

---

then my problem is when i go back ( from summary ) its clear params on previous. so when i go back the view is **create home** , my expected is **view home**.

i looking for best tricks ...

i have code

```
hasHistory() {
      return window.history.length > 3
    },
```

but in other case i have much page (more than 4 pages ) so its not solve .

Answer (score 1):

This part of the code the person in the other question put to check that the user would "go back" to their application and not a 3rd party's website. If you want to keep that functionality I suggest you keep that as:

```
hasHistory() {
      // this can stay at 2 and your user will only navigate "back" if the last route was part of your app
      return window.history.length > 2;
}
```

To go back one page you can do `$router.go(-1)` or `$router.back()` like so: `<button @click="$router.go(-1)">back</button>`.

If you need to add the params you can use `beforeRouteEnter` navigation guard and use `router.push()` in your back button. Here's some boilerplate:

```
// Summary.vue
<template>
    <button @click="$router.push(previousRoute)>Back</button>
</template>

<script>
    beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
        next(vm => {
            vm.previousRoute = from;
        });
    },
    data () {
        return {
            previousRoute: undefined
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: i think its will complicated if use vuex , now i use my trick with passing ```currentRoute``` ```previous_link: { name: 'list-home' }``` so when i need go back .. i use  ```:to="$router.currentRoute.params.previous_link"```

Comment: After thinking about it, you could avoid using the state completely and use the component navigation guard `beforeRouteEnter` in `Summary.vue`

Answer (score 1):

`router.go/router.back` are very close to `window.history.go` APIs which need strict debugging if it comes to history manipulation and we manage them by using tricks like hardcode the numbers, `router.go(1)`, `router.go(2)`, etc.

If you are looking for a better approach for router navigation (forward and backward), write the navigation process inside the route's meta properties.

For example, if you want to navigate back from `Summary.vue` page to `ViewHome.vue` page, then you can write this logic inside your summary route like this-

```
{
  path: "/summary",
  name: "Summary",
  component: "SummaryComponent"
  meta: {
    backRoute: "ViewHome"
  },
},
```

And your back button inside `Summary.vue` would look like this-

```
<button @click=$router.push({ name: $route.meta.backRoute })>Go Back</button>
```

Using this approach you will always be sure that back button from `Summary.vue` page will always redirect to `ViewHome.vue` page.

The same meta-property concept can be used for all routes you want to navigate forward and backward.

Comment: let me test it wait , I doubt about the params , because view home need dataID /props.row.detail_id .

Comment: i think i just use my trick ```previous_link: $router.currentRoute``` on any ```params``` have the properties.  because if wee need to keep the last `detail id` still need/use `vuex `. but thankyou if we use like above the code will be more clean, nice.